# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2 - n+1}-\left\lfloor\sqrt {n^2 - n+1}\right\rfloor\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> How do I evaluate
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2-n+1}-\left\lfloor\sqrt{n^2 - n+1}\right\rfloor\right),n\in\Bbb N$$

**Attempt:**

I thought of using Squeeze theorem but that could not help.

Secondly, we know that $x- \lfloor x\rfloor=\{x\}$ where $\{\}$ denotes the fractional part function. But I am not sure how to actually evaluate limits involving the fractional part function.

Comment: Hint: $n - 1 < \sqrt{n^2 - n + 1} < n$.

Comment: "But I am not sure how to actually evaluate limits involving the fractional part function." One common way is to switch out $\{x\}$ with $x-[x]$, and then... Oh, wait.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since $n - 1 < \sqrt{n^2 - n + 1} < n$, then\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} \sqrt{n^2 - n + 1} - [\sqrt{n^2 - n + 1}] = \sqrt{n^2 - n + 1} - (n - 1)\\
&= \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2 - n + 1} + (n - 1)} → \frac{1}{2}. \quad (n → ∞)
\end{align*}

Comment: I dont see why the first line is true.

Comment: @Neymar Squaring them and you could see.

Comment: (n-1)^2 < n^2-n+1<n^2 how come this true ?

Comment: also, why the second is equality but you has inequality in the first line. so confusing

Comment: As $n\to\infty$, we can assume that $n>1$, then $(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1<n^2-n+1<n^2$. Take the square root and we arrive at the first inequality. If we take $n\in\mathbb Z$, then we can use the definition of the floor function to write $[\sqrt{n^2-n+1}]=n-1$.